# How do you open gold chests in Magicite?

Tags: magicite

How do you open gold chests in Magicite?  Do you need the lock picking skill or do you need to find a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either

1. Golden key, or
2. "Open golden chest without keys" trait.